# Using select by attributes across mutliple layers in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, select-by-attribute, arcgis-10.8

I am using ArcMap 10.8.2.

I'm working on a GIS update for a local municipality. They've asked that I only send them back data that I've added or changed.

It seems the easiest way for me to do this would be to isolate out everything that I've tagged as edited by "me", and split it out to a separate file geoDB to send back to the client.

However, I'm having trouble making that work. If I try to select by attributes, I have to select one layer (feature class) at a time, which would take forever, since there are a LOT of layers in this project.

How can I set up a query to do this or is there an easier way to separate out a subset of data across multiple classes, so I can send it to my client?

Answer (score 3):

You can build a model (see [What is ModelBuilder?](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/what-is-modelbuilder.htm)) with an [Iterate Feature Classes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-feature-classes.htm) iterator which:

> Iterates over feature classes in a Workspace or Feature Dataset.

followed by [Select](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/select.htm) which:

> Extracts features from an input feature class or input feature layer,
> typically using a select or Structured Query Language (SQL) expression
> and stores them in an output feature class.